# Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode

Tags: java, drools

Estoy creando un bundle con drools donde al momento de correr una clase main de test me devuelve Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode

Mi clase Main (TestFunciones.java)

```
public class TestFunciones{

    public static final void main(String[]args){
        PeticionFel req = new PeticionFel();

        try{
            KieContainer kc = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
            KieSession kss = kc.newKieSession("k-reglas");

            System.setProperty("drools.dialect.mvel.strict", "false"); 

            kss.insert(GranTotal(req));
            kss.fireAllRules();
            System.out.println("Cambió a estado: " + req.getDescripcion());
            System.out.println("**********FIN DEL BUNDLE VALIDACIONES PARTE TRES**********");
        }catch(Throwable t){
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + t);
        }
    }

    public static PeticionFel GranTotal(PeticionFel req){

        try{
            JAXBContext jaxbC = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.base");
            Unmarshaller jaxbUn = jaxbC.createUnmarshaller();

            InputStream strm = new ByteArrayInputStream(req.getCarga_util().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));

            GTDocumento test = (GTDocumento) jaxbUn.unmarshal(strm);

            GTDocumento.SAT uDTE = (GTDocumento.SAT) test.getContent().get(0).getValue();

            if(!uDTE.getDTE().getDatosEmision().getItems().getItem().isEmpty()){

                System.out.println("La cantidad de items es: " + uDTE.getDTE().getDatosEmision().getItems().getItem().size());

                List<GTDocumento.SAT.DTE.DatosEmision.Items.Item> lines = new ArrayList<>();
                lines = uDTE.getDTE().getDatosEmision().getItems().getItem();

                lines.stream()
                        .filter(p -> p.getPrecio() == p.getPrecio().plus(MathContext.UNLIMITED))
                        .forEach((p)-> {
                    System.out.println("PRECIO " + p.getPrecio());

                });

                lines.forEach((invoice) -> System.out.println("PRECIO: " + invoice.getPrecio() + " de la línea " + invoice.getNumeroLinea()));
                BigDecimal sumas = lines.stream().map((x) -> x.getPrecio()).reduce((x, y) -> x.add(y)).get();
                System.out.println("SUMA = " + sumas);

                BigDecimal total = uDTE.getDTE().getDatosEmision().getTotales().getGranTotal();
                System.out.println("GRAN TOTAL: " + total);

                int comparar = sumas.compareTo(total);

                if(comparar == 0){
                    System.out.println("Gran Total calculado correctamente");
                }

            }else{
                System.err.println("La casilla de ITEM no está presente en el XML");
            }

        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException | JAXBException t){
            System.err.println("Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }

        return req;
    }

}
```

---

ARCHIVO TestFunciones.java

```
package com.principal;

import com.base.GTDocumento;
import estructuras.PeticionFel;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

/**
 * @author einsen
 */
public class TestFunciones {

    public static final void main(String[]args){
        PeticionFel req = new PeticionFel();

        try{
            KieContainer kc = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
            KieSession kss = kc.newKieSession("k-reglas");

            System.setProperty("drools.dialect.mvel.strict", "false"); 

            kss.insert(GranTotal(req));
            kss.fireAllRules();
            System.out.println("Cambió a estado: " + req.getDescripcion());
            System.out.println("**********FIN DEL BUNDLE VALIDACIONES PARTE TRES**********");
        }catch(Throwable t){
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + t);
        }
    }

    public static PeticionFel GranTotal(PeticionFel req){

        try{
            JAXBContext jaxbC = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.base");
            Unmarshaller jaxbUn = jaxbC.createUnmarshaller();

            InputStream strm = new ByteArrayInputStream(req.getCarga_util().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));

            GTDocumento test = (GTDocumento) jaxbUn.unmarshal(strm);

            GTDocumento.SAT uDTE = (GTDocumento.SAT) test.getContent().get(0).getValue();

            if(!uDTE.getDTE().getDatosEmision().getItems().getItem().isEmpty()){

                System.out.println("La cantidad de items es: " + uDTE.getDTE().getDatosEmision().getItems().getItem().size());

                List<GTDocumento.SAT.DTE.DatosEmision.Items.Item> lines = new ArrayList<>();
                lines = uDTE.getDTE().getDatosEmision().getItems().getItem();

                lines.stream()
                        .filter(p -> p.getPrecio() == p.getPrecio().plus(MathContext.UNLIMITED))
                        .forEach((p)-> {
                    System.out.println("PRECIO " + p.getPrecio());

                });

                lines.forEach((invoice) -> System.out.println("PRECIO: " + invoice.getPrecio() + " de la línea " + invoice.getNumeroLinea()));
                BigDecimal sumas = lines.stream().map((x) -> x.getPrecio()).reduce((x, y) -> x.add(y)).get();
                System.out.println("SUMA = " + sumas);

                BigDecimal total = uDTE.getDTE().getDatosEmision().getTotales().getGranTotal();
                System.out.println("GRAN TOTAL: " + total);

                int comparar = sumas.compareTo(total);

                if(comparar == 0){
                    System.out.println("Gran Total calculado correctamente");
                }

            }else{
                System.err.println("La casilla de ITEM no está presente en el XML");
            }

        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException | JAXBException t){
            System.err.println("Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }

        return req;
    }

}
```

---

ARCHIVO DRL

```
package com.principal

import com.principal.Funciones.*;
import com.base.GTDocumento;
import estructuras.PeticionFel;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;


rule "Total Total"

when
    $total : TestFunciones(GranTotal())
then
    System.err.println("ERROR. Gran Total calculado incorrectamente. El contenido de la casilla <dte:GranTotal>"
                    + "es diferente a la sumatoria de las casillas <dte:Total>");
end
```

Comment: Pon el código de lo que estás intentando

Comment: Listo @AdrianaHernández, gracias de antemano

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el código ahí, no como respuesta

Comment: Listo @PabloLozano, de antemano gracias por la ayuda

Comment: gracias por la edición @Alvaro Montoro♦, es mi primera vez utilizando stack

Comment: Sin problemas. Estamos para ayudar en lo que se pueda :)